# Codeplex source view? What would the most up to date Nuget Package XSD be?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, xsd, nuget

So, looking though the source code for a more up-to-date XSD I find found something from 2010/07, which seems kind of old, and must be, because generating a package uses elements like `<releaseNotes/>`.

When I looked through some source code I see that there are place holders in this [XSD](http://nuget.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/d35f511ab392#src/Core/Authoring/nuspec.xsd) that fill in some xmlns attributes.  I'd like to find a full version of this XSD with the proper values, if possible?  It seems a little strange that Nuget.exe doesn't output the xsd namespace values when running a Nuget.exe spec [...] command (oh well).  That would give me a clue as to what should be placed in the XSD.

At the moment I'm just trying to get intellisense to work correctly using VS using [XSD](http://nuget.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/d35f511ab392#src/Core/Authoring/nuspec.xsd) schema.  I can fake the values for the time being -- just to get intellisense working. Nuget must be under some heavy development if the number of Tickets/Issues (400+) are an indicator, so perhaps anything really stable is unlikely for a while?  I would guess that this is the latest [XSD](http://nuget.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/d35f511ab392#src/Core/Authoring/nuspec.xsd)?  Is there perhaps a full version (without format placeholders) somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

Codeplex is your best bet for an up to date schema. If you need one for a specific version, consider going back to a tagged release and using that one.